# How to migrate xml files created by XmlSerializer so it can be loaded by DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, migration, xmlserializer, datacontractserializer

I'm writing migration code for an application data. We want to retire the use of XmlSerializer and have DataContractSerializer as the only xml serializer used throughout the application.

The first solution that came to mind was to Use XmlSerializer to deserialize the xml content on memory and then follow with re-serialization using DataContractSerializer.

However, since this is migration code, I cannot use the type used to serialize (the data contract) given that the we would be using the "current" implementation of that type which will change with time.

In other words, is there a way to edit the xml file in order to make it compatible with DataContractSerializer ?

Comment: One possibility would be to copy/paste a snapshot of your types into a separate data conversion Assembly, retaining both the data contract and XmlSerializer attributes but otherwise stripped of their business logic, and use that to do the conversion.  Beyond that, this question seems too general for stackoverflow.  Can you break it down into specific problems, like 1) Using Linq-to-XML, demote attributes to elements, or 2) Using XPath, convert one-level lists to two levels?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It seems like a reasonable alternative. I didn't understand what you mean by too general for stackoverflow. What is a good place to post a question such is that one?